# I cannot install anything with apt or apt-get

Tags: apt, debconf

Whenever I try to install something on my ubuntu 22.4, it returns this error

```
root@lucie-Precision-Tower-3620:/home/lucie/Programs/perl-5.38.0# sudo apt install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  make-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  make
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 180 kB of archives.
After this operation, 426 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 make amd64 4.3-4.1build1 [180 kB]
Fetched 180 kB in 0s (989 kB/s)
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found
Setting up debconf (1.5.79ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/debconf.postinst: 17: exec: /usr/share/debconf/frontend: not found
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 installed debconf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

but /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure and /usr/share/debconf/frontend  are there..
Could it be that perl is not installed ? (I cannot manage to install it without make, that I don't have)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have somehow removed the `debconf` package